# Maximum number of sample per pixel supported by Indigo Renderer

Tags: 3d, renderer, scene, 3dsmax

I would like to know the maximum number of sample per pixel supported by Indigo Renderer.
I haven't found my answer in the manual, neither in the technical reference.

Can you help me please ?

Thank you in advance ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no 'max', you can render forever if you want with unbiased renderers like these. But after a while it does not make sense to keep on rendering, because all the pixels has been sampled enough for you to see no improvement in the image.